# What is the equivalent of apt-key in yum?

Tags: yum, amazon-ami

I am following a tutorial that can be found here to set up a headless selenium scraper on an ec2 instance:

https://krbnite.github.io/Driving-Headless-Chrome-with-Selenium-on-AWS-EC2/

The tutorial I am using seems to assume an ubuntu distro whereas the ec2 instance I am using is an AWS AMI. As such apt-get is not available to me and instead I use yum to install things.

The first step of the installation process is the following:

```
wget -q -O - "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub" | sudo apt-key add -
```

When I do this I get the following, to be expected error on my AWS AMI instance:

```
sudo: apt-key: command not found
```

I was wondering what the equivalent command would be without using apt, apt-get, or apt-key but instead using yum. I have blindly tried the following but they did not work:

```
wget -q -O - "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub" | sudo yum add -

wget -q -O - "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub" | sudo yum-key add -
```

Thanks

Comment: `wget -q -O /path/to/key "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub"; rpm --import /path/to/key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Below is from an article on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/yum-and-apt)  which I think answers this questions properly:**

Adding a repository in YUM is a manual operation, which consists in creating a file with the .repo extension under the folder /etc/yum.repos.d.

The file must contain all the information about the custom repository that we are connecting to.

Let’s try adding the AdoptOpenJDK repository:

```
# /etc/yum.repos.d/adoptopenjdk.repo
[AdoptOpenJDK]
name=AdoptOpenJDK
baseurl=http://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/rpm/centos/7/$(uname -m)
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public
```

In APT, though, things are quite different. The GPG key of the repository must be downloaded and added to the APT keyring with apt-key add:

```
wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then, at this point, the repository can be added through `add-apt-repository –yes` followed by the URL:

```
add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
```

Contrary to YUM, all the repositories are saved in a single file,
`/etc/apt/sources.list.`

Answer (score 1):

Add the repo and then import the repo GPG key

```
sudo wget -o /etc/yum.repos.d/reponame.repo <repo url>
sudo rpm --import <key url>
```

Confirm

```
yum repolist
```